# Select Values of XML with values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Hi I am stuck trying to get all of the values needed in an xml. My first task is to traverse the many different elements available and only output the name when id is a value.

For example, I am trying to output first name when id =2. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<Section>
      <Instance id = "1"></Instance>
      <First>James</First>
      <Last>Potter</Last>
 </Section>
 <Section>
      <Instance id = "2"></Instance>
      <First>Lily</First>
      <Last>Potter</Last>
  </Section>
```

The goal is when id = 2, return the First  name, so Lily.

What I tried to do is the following, but it does not seem to be working.

```
 <xsl:for-each select="Section/id@Descriptor = '2'">
    <xsl:value-of select="../First"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please post a **complete and well-formed** example of the input - as well as the expected result. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Your input is still incomplete (no root element) and your XSLT snippet is missing the most important thing in XSLT - **context**. But perhaps you meant:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Section[Instance/@id=2]">
    <xsl:value-of select="First"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an XSLT 2.0 processor and `version="2.0"` in your stylesheet then all you need is

```
<xsl:value-of select="Section[Instance/@id = 2]/First"/>
```

There is no need for `for-each` in that case.